# How to get file name using C++17 Filesystem

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a path `"C:/SomeFolder/sometextfile.txt"`. How can a file name, `"sometextfile.txt"`, be extracted from a path using C++17 filesystem library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [filename method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename).

```
std::filesystem::path p("C:/SomeFolder/sometextfile.txt");
auto name = p.filename();
```

Comment: I will add `p.make_preferred()` before calling `filename()`. This just converts the path seperators to the one preferred by the os. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/make_preferred

Comment: Why?  Would path separators ever be in the result of `filename()`?  For other purposes, I could understand this.

Comment: The "preferred separator" is just the system default. A forward slash works just as fine on Windows.